# Robo 3T: Can not connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

Got an error, "**Cannot connect to the MongoDB at localhost:27017.**" when I try to connect to MongoDB using Robo 3T even though the mongo server is running. I worked for two days with Robo 3T and it worked pretty much fine and suddenly got this error. (I worked on my Node project and while I was connecting to Robo 3T with the mongo server running my lap powered off suddenly. When I restarted and tried to connect this error occurred.)

[image: o]

**Error:
Network is unreachable. Reason: couldn't connect to server localhost:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to localhost:27017 (127.0.0.1:27017) :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**

Comment: `Ctrl+C` is your friend - should work also on error dialogs.

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB?

Comment: Yes. I started MongoDB using cmd @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Where do you suggest me to use Ctrl+C in this case @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: In order to get the full error message text. You cannot read the screenshot at all, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Sorry, it is my bad. I modified the question with the full error @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Mongodb is not running.

Comment: @AlexBlex MongoDB was running. I started Mongo server using cmd but got this error. I tried several times by running MongoDB again and again but nothing has changed.

Comment: Are there any prerequisites rather than starting MongoDB?

Comment: What is the error message when you try to start the MongoDB?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The error is Error: Network is unreachable. Reason: couldn't connect to server localhost:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to localhost:27017 (127.0.0.1:27017) :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: You write "I **started** Mongo server using cmd but got this error"  - that's not possible. You cannot get a connection error when you try to start the MongoDB. You said, you restarted your laptop. It really looks like your MonogDB is not running.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit After I restarted the lap I opened the cmd and made the MongoDB run. Then tried to connect and got this error. Even I am confused about how it happened.

Comment: Did you check the MongoDB logs?

Comment: @stp_ which command did you use to start mongodb in the cmd

Comment: @AlexBlex I used "mongod" command

Comment: good, so it's not a service, and all errors should be printed right there. Copy output from there to the question. As  Wernfried Domscheit suggested your symptoms indicate there was no line `waiting for connections on port 27017`. Now there are many possible causes why it happened - file locks/errors, misconfiguration, permissions etc. We may be able to narrow it down if we see the output of the `mongod` command. Please include the command itself if you run it with any parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the MongoDB is started after restarting the system.

Also, check the port and IP in the mongo config file which is you are trying to connect using the robo3t